# Unchecking radiobutton list using jquery

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

Ok, last question for today I promise!

I have the following line of code that features a radio button list (radTopx)

`ddlBuyer.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#tbxProdAC').val('');     $('#txtbxHowMany').val(''); $('#GridView1').remove(); $('#radTopx').attr('checked',false); ");`

What I am trying to achieve is that when ddlBuyer is clicked, radTopx has all it's radio buttons unchecked.

I am obviously doing this incorrectly at present, please can someone pointout where I have gone wrong? Does this work differently in a radio button list to a standard radio button?

Where #radTopx represents the following radio button list :

RadioButtonList ID="radTopx"

```
    ListItem>UUF1<ListItem>
    ListItem>UUF2<ListItem>
    ListItem>UUF3<ListItem>
```

RadioButtonList

Comment: My apologies, #radTopx is a radiobutton list

Comment: do mean something that contains a radio button list, like a div? Since a radio button is an `<input />` a group of them can't have the same id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#ddlBuyer').click(function() {
    $('div#radios input').attr('checked',false);
});
```

where `div#radios` encloses all your radio inputs. I'm assuming `ddlBuyer` is the id of something that gets clicked.

We can't give an answer in regard to `#radTopx` since we don't know what it is.

Comment: Sorry, I was making my way back home.And you are correct, ddlBuyer is indeed a drop down list that gets clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Carillonator, greatly appreciated.

The following code did the trick, I just need to add in the 'input'

`ddlBuyer.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#tbxProdAC').val('');     $('#txtbxHowMany').val(''); $('#GridView1').remove(); $('#radTopx input').attr('checked',false); ");`

Where #radTopx is the radio button list.

Comment: I believe you are missing some basic understanding of jQuery, adding the "attribute" of onclick is basically the same as adding the .click() event handler from jQuery so you could have done:
$('#tbxProdAC').val('');
$('#txtbxHowMany').val(''); 
$('#GridView1').remove();
$('#radTopx input').attr('checked',false);

all inside the selector function() as carillonator illustrated and thus NOT have to add the attribute.

Comment: OR, perhaps you have a specific reason to do it your way - just pointing out that it is all possible in one function.

Comment: Nope you're right Mark - I do lack a lot of understanding at th is moment in time...unfortunately I need to get some work done asap for demo purposes, I'll then go back and work on best practise and amend the code where appropriate. Thank you for the heads up though Mark, I definitely need pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#radTopx').prop('checked',false);
```